# How to make is_rtl() return as true

Tags: wordpress, right-to-left

I switch wordpress locale from one language to another via a GET variable and based on the value of GET the appropriate fonts and css etc are loaded fine. However the main style.css remains the same as the language specific css are loaded on top of that.

Except there are some RTL languages. For them my main style.css also needs to be switched from style.css to style-rtl.css.

The code I have is as follows:

```
if( !is_rtl() ) { // if LTR
    wp_enqueue_style('direction-style', get_template_directory_uri()."/style.css",array(), null);
} else { // if RTL
    wp_enqueue_style('direction-style', get_template_directory_uri()."/style-rtl.css",array(), null);
}
```

Now I need a command to make [is_rtl()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_rtl/) return as true. I searched the internet but couldn't find it. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add to the code an example of the part where you set the locale and where it is located in the code? (can it be possible that the locale is set **after** this test is made?)

Comment: @Kaddath the local is set via a hook [https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale] using the add_filter( 'locale',) while the styles are set using add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',..)
I think the wp_enqueue_scripts hook is triggered prior to locale so you might probably be right... But I also don't know a way to set locale before add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts')

Comment: It's been quite long i haven't messed with init steps.. you can confirm if it's the source of the problem by either build a debug variable (which can be displayed in your pages with an HTML comment for example) that shows the order of the 2 actions, or also by setting manually your locale to a `rtl` value at the beginning of the file and see if you pass the test

Comment: On which hook run your code with `is_rtl`? The function need the global `$wp_locale` and there is not active on unr via php instance. Your code should run lately, like via `plugins_loaded` Hook.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved.

Actually the problem was caused by running the above code from the function.php file of the Wordpress theme.

The locale hook needs to be called from a plugin and not from a theme, becuase by the time WordPress loads a theme, it’s already too late.

Once called from a plugin, the is_rtl() automatically returns true for a locale that is by default RTL.

As an added benefit one may also add the following attribute to the body tag

```
dir="<?php echo $GLOBALS['text_direction']; ?>"
```